# Scalding: How to reduce in-memory computations on lists?

Tags: algorithm, scala, hadoop, scalding

With Scalding I try to find edit-distances between pairs of similar strings. All in all I have 10 000 000 strings in a CSV file. To reduce computations I use the following algorithm:

1. Split all strings in groups by using first three chars as a key
2. Generate combinations of two strings in every group
3. Find edit distance for every pair of strings in every group (see code below)

When I run this algorithm on HDFS it works with 1 000 000 of strings. With 10 000 000 of strings node manager complains about my 'map' jobs attempts to allocate more physical memory then node has. I understand that this condition occurs when huge number of combinations is created in `.groupBy('key) { _.mapList ...}` code. Certainly this algorithm does not really scale.

Please advise other approaches to reduce computations for this task.

```
import cascading.tuple.Fields
import com.twitter.scalding._

class Proto1(args: Args) extends Job(args) {
  val outputStr = "tmp/out.txt"
  val output = TextLine(outputStr)

  val wordsList = List(
    ("aaaa"),
    ("aaaa"),
    ("aaaad"),
    ("aaaab"),
    ("aaabb"),
    ("aabbcc"),
    ("aaabccdd"),
    ("aaabbccdde"),
    ("aaabbddd"),
    ("bbbb"),
    ("bbbb"),
    ("bbbaaa"),
    ("bbaaabb"),
    ("bbbcccc"),
    ("bbbddde"),
    ("bbbdddd"),
    ("bbbdddf"),
    ("bbbdddd"),
    ("ccccc"),
    ("cccaaa"),
    ("ccccaabbb"),
    ("ccbbbddd"),
    ("cdddeee"),
    ("ddd"),
    ("ddd")
    )

  val orderedPipe =
    IterableSource[(String)](wordsList, ('word))
      .map('word -> 'key) { word: String => word.take(3) }
      .debug
      //.groupBy('key) { _.toList[String]('word -> 'list) }
      //.debug
      .groupBy('key) { _.mapList[String, List[(String, String, Int)]]('word -> 'list)(editDistances) }
      .filterNot('key, 'list) { fields: (String, List[(String, String, Int)]) =>
        val (key, list) = fields
        list.isEmpty
      }
      .flatMapTo('list -> ('str1, 'str2, 'dist)) {list:List[(String, String, Int)] => list  }
      .debug
      //.write(output)
      .write(Csv(outputStr))

  def editDistances(list: List[String]): List[(String, String, Int)] = {

    val resultList = list.combinations(2).toList.map(x => (x(0), x(1), editDistance(x(0), x(1))))
        //println(resultList+"\n")
    val result = resultList.filter(x => x._3 <= 1)
    result
  }

  def editDistance(a: String, b: String): Int = {

    import scala.math.min

    def min3(x: Int, y: Int, z: Int) = min(min(x, y), z)

    val (m, n) = (a.length, b.length)

    val matrix = Array.fill(m + 1, n + 1)(0)

    for (i <- 0 to m; j <- 0 to n) {

      matrix(i)(j) = if (i == 0) j
      else if (j == 0) i
      else if (a(i - 1) == b(j - 1)) matrix(i - 1)(j - 1)
      else min3(
        matrix(i - 1)(j) + 1,
        matrix(i)(j - 1) + 1,
        matrix(i - 1)(j - 1) + 1)
    }

    matrix(m)(n)
  }

}
```

Any ideas?

Comment: You'll have to give more context as to what it is you want in the end.  I.e. are you then going to threshold to take all pairs that have an editDistance less than some amount??  As you have decuced, the problem is when you call `.combinations(2)` for a large group.  Two things you can try are: using lazy collections, so `Iterators` instead of lists - this will mean the combinations won't be evaluated until you call `flatMapTo`. Another thing is just change 3 chars to 4 :)

Comment: Yes,I also did filtering to take pairs with distance < some threshold. I also used a key of 4 chars. Nothing of this solves the problem. Could you please give an example of using `Iterators` in Scalding? Thanks!